# How to ignore Login for another Route using react-router-dom v5

Tags: reactjs, routes, react-router, react-router-dom

Here I have a already built vuexy template where it has a setup like if user gets logout it routed to the /login , but I'm setting up Forgot Password / Functionality where user will only have email to make post request and in this case I want to route to another route like /password-reset-request , Now this setup is preventing me to achieve it, anybody knows how to do that .

They setup is like that using `"react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",`
this link is in login page

```
<Link className='brand-logo mb-0' to='/password-reset-request' onClick={e => e.preventDefault()}>
        <span className='brand-logo mb-0'>
          Forgot Password ?
        </span> 
        </Link>
```

EDIT :

```
export const authSlice = createSlice({
  name: 'authentication',
  initialState: {
    userData: initialUser()
  },
  reducers: {
    handleLogin: (state, action) => {
      state.userData = action.payload
      state[config.storageTokenKeyName] = action.payload[config.storageTokenKeyName]
      state[config.storageRefreshTokenKeyName] = action.payload[config.storageRefreshTokenKeyName]
      localStorage.setItem('userData', JSON.stringify(action.payload))
      localStorage.setItem(config.storageTokenKeyName, JSON.stringify(action.payload.accessToken))
      localStorage.setItem(config.storageRefreshTokenKeyName, JSON.stringify(action.payload.refreshToken))
    },
    handleLogout: state => {
      state.userData = {}
      state[config.storageTokenKeyName] = null
      state[config.storageRefreshTokenKeyName] = null
      // ** Remove user, accessToken & refreshToken from localStorage
      localStorage.removeItem('userData')
      localStorage.removeItem(config.storageTokenKeyName)
      localStorage.removeItem(config.storageRefreshTokenKeyName)
    }
  }
})

export const { handleLogin, handleLogout } = authSlice.actions

export default authSlice.reducer
```

If handleLogout called then it redirects to /login

```
{
    path: '/login',
    component: lazy(() => import('../../views/Login')),
    layout: 'BlankLayout', //
    meta: {
      authRoute: true
    }
  },
{
    path: '/password-reset-request',
    component: lazy(() => import('../../views/AuthComponents/ForgotPassword'))
  },
```

My main point is if userData is not in local storage then user can also go to /loing and /password-reset-request if he wants to.

Comment: What do you have, or want, to differentiate the home `"/"` path to redirect to one or the other of those paths? Is this complete code? Where is the redirect to login?

Comment: I'm updating the question

Comment: Do you *need* two different redirect targets from the root `"/"` path?

Comment: Yes for example if userData is not in localStorage, /login route always remains active , but I want this functionality with 2 more routes for means , if user come to login he can go to /reset-password-request if he wants

Comment: Wouldn't/shouldn't this just be a link to "forgot password" or "reset password" from the login page then, if that's what the user is deciding to do? If just landing on `"/"` how should app know where to redirect?

Comment: Sorry I mistyped above, I meant to say , When logout function called , user gets routed to /login automatically, if there is userData then other pages are accessible. But if userData is not there login route is always active

Comment: And also added the login route in the question please take a look

Comment: Sorry, I'm even more lost now what the issue/question is. Are you saying that a user logs out and gets redirected to `"/login"`.... and ... then .... you want to get redirected to a `"/password-reset"` route?

Comment: Yes on the login Page there is a link to go to reset password if user dosnt knows the password . and now this link is not working, due to logic in the routes to keep the user just on login page

Comment: My main point is if userData is not in local storage then user can also go to /login and /password-reset-request if he wants to.

Comment: So what is the problem then? Are you rendering a route and path for `"/password-reset-request"`?

Comment: :) The problem is to='/password-reset-request' route dosnt working

Comment: `Route` components use a `path` prop, not a `to` prop, try `path='/password-reset-request'`.

Comment: thanks for letting me know but this is not working

Comment: If the `Link` in your question is the link to that page then it's not working because you added an `onClick` handler and are preventing the default event action from occurring.

Comment: OMG yes that was the problem

Comment: No worries, we all get the code blinders on sometimes. Voted to close as "Not reproducible or was caused by a typo". Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is that, in your reducer you've only 2 options login and logout and in case user is not logged in, will not be able to access other pages, there are 3 ways to solve it:

- Before redirecting the user to log in check the route he/she is trying to access
- you can use a private route for authentication
- you can create middleware with high order function to check authentication instead of reducer